# JHipster mySQL in development

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jhipster

I want to use mySQL in development mode with JHipster 3.4.2. 
I generated the app with the generator and installed docker and docker-compose. When start the `docker-compose -f src/main/docker/mysql.yml up` and run the app with `./mvnw` I get the stack trace:

```
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:528)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:118)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:94)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:388)
    at eu.biasion.nbmf.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.initDb(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:66)
    at eu.biasion.nbmf.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$0(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:49)
    at eu.biasion.nbmf.async.ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.lambda$createWrappedRunnable$17(ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

I did not find guide about using mySQL with Jhipster in development mode. I am very thankful for any advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use Docker's MySQL container with the mvn project running locally, you need to change src/main/resources/config/application-dev.yml to point at Docker's IP rather than localhost. This lets you continue to use live-reload and BrowserSync.

The property to change is `spring.datasource.url`.  In my case, Docker runs on 192.168.99.100 so the updated section of application-dev.yml should look like:

```
spring:
    devtools:
        restart:
            enabled: true
        livereload:
            enabled: false # we use gulp + BrowserSync for livereload
    datasource:
        url: jdbc:mysql://192.168.99.100:3306/chat?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Jhipster and docker as well. I used MySql as database and used docker-compose to run application inside docker container.  Following the steps outlined in the pages [here](https://jhipster.github.io/docker-compose/)

Create docker image of application using : `./mvnw package -Pprod docker:build`

Here you can change prod profile to dev if needed.

Then start application including mysql using command: `docker-compose -f src/main/docker/app.yml up`

Looks like you are trying to run only mysql service in docker but you want to run application on host?

Comment: Thanks, i am also new to Jhipster and docker! Actually i want to run the application on the host. The way you explained works. It just took me some time to recognise that the app is accessible at http://192.168.99.100:8080 instead of http://127.0.0.1:8080, as printed in the console :)

Comment: Is there a big advantage of using docker in development as a single developer?
In my opinion rebuilding with every change in Angular, missing live reload and and browsersync slows down the dev process. Do you know whats the problem posted above when running just mysql in docker and the application on the host?

Comment: For single developer, I think using docker in development gives i) Exact same environment as the production ii) You don't have to install development environment - instead you can just use jhipster docker image iii) makes it easy to work around multiple versions of languages (if you have to use different version of say java on different applications). In this case, you would just use respective java version docker image. BTW, if you think my answer has helped you, can you mark my answer as accepted?  It will help my reputation on SO. I am new to Stackoverflow. Thanks!